# Does "javax.persistence.EntityManager.find(Class<ClassName> arg0, Object arg1)" search arg0's subclasses?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, entitymanager

I built entities with `@Inheritance(strategy=inheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` annotation. And I specified them with `@DiscriminatorValue("xxx")` . Now I passed `BaseClass.class` into `entityManager.find` method. Would it returns a subclass Object?

If not, how to save codes to implements similar function between those subclasses?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly it does. If "id" corresponds to Subclass then it returns an instance of Subclass, aka polymorphism. But then you could just try it!

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'll try it out.:) @NeilStockton